# Toggle/Slide expand works, but collapse does not work with HTML Arrow.

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

i wish to have slide/toggle of a div with a html entity (arrow) as a trigger for toggle.
All works ok except when the div is expanded the arrow up won't toggle the content back up.

Here is a demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tkmW/ - expand works, collapse doesn't.
(don't know if the `↑` is valid to put inside)

Any help appriciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a class which you'll toggle when the box is collapsed or expanded. In the following example I have been using `collapsed` class.

<kbd>[Here's a Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/8tkmW/1/)</kbd>

```
var collapsedSize = '40px';
$('.content').each(function() {
    var h = this.scrollHeight;
    console.log(h);
    var div = $(this);
    if (h > 30) {
        div.css('height', collapsedSize);
        div.after('<a class="arrow-link collapsed" href="#">&#8595;</a><br/>');
        var link = div.next();
        link.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (link.hasClass('collapsed')) {
                link.html('&#8593;');
                div.animate({
                    'height': h
                });
                link.removeClass('collapsed')
            } else {
                div.animate({
                    'height': collapsedSize
                });
                link.addClass('collapsed')
                link.html('&#8595;');
            }

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: hmm, this code doesn't seem to work in IE9 - any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I've opened the demo fiddle in IE9 and the content is expanded (no arrows are showing). Maybe it's something wrong on my browser. Is the fiddle working on your side if you open it in IE9?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have IE on my ubuntu. Check the console for warning or Error. You could also open a new thread